# Random restarts on Intel NUC with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hardware, restart

My machine (Intel Nuc) with Ubuntu 20.04 restarts randomly at times; frequency is about once per day.

`dmesg | grep -i error` shows

```
[    2.038129] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    2.082714] BERT: Error records from previous boot:
[    2.082715] [Hardware Error]: event severity: fatal
[    2.082716] [Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: fatal
[    2.082717] [Hardware Error]:   section type: unknown, 81212a96-09ed-4996-9471-8d729c8e69ed
[    2.082718] [Hardware Error]:   section length: 0xc20
[    2.082719] [Hardware Error]:   00000000: 00000001 00000000 00000000 01001003  ................
```

Any ideas what the cause is and how to fix it? Is it a harddisk error? Strange coincidence: the restarts started after an upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what does S.M.A.R.T tell you you can find this in GNOME discs

Comment: I have the same error with my NUC8i5BEH, and appeared to start after the 20.04 upgrade. Looking online it's possibly an error with sleep/hibernation, although I have these turned off... googling the "section type" will provide others with similar issues: e.g.
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-NUCs/Intel-Nuc-with-Ubuntu-20-04-randomly-reboots/td-p/674721?profile.language=en
https://www.reddit.com/r/intelnuc/comments/9q6k3a/nuc8i5bek_randomly_reboots/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. SMART unfortunately doesn‘t help since it‘s a Nvme disc. I have also turned hibernation off. For some reason, the system is stable in the last couple of days. Still, not very satisfying.

Comment: We've had similar log, when server freezed. It was reported in BMC as CATERR processor error, so it could be bad processor unit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a NUC5i7RYH with a Crucial NVME drive. I was advised to set BIOS to boot Legacy rather than UEFI when installing an NVME drive as a boot drive.

Resetting the drive to Legacy Boot did require a complete reinstallation of OS but did resolve all issues with performance. Linux or Windows OS resolved.

This same method did NOT resolve random reboot issues on a NUC6i5SYH.
It seems that for all Intel NUC6 (any CPU) and above require the latest BIOS revision and to disable "Watchdog" (uncheck) in the system visual BIOS regardless of UEFI or Legacy choice at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up against this issue. I have updated the bios to `BE0085.bio` from the intel website here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29959/BIOS-Update-BECFL357-86A-

I want to see if this helps. If not, the next step is to replace the NVME drive, currently rocking 1TB Samsung 970 evo.

Comment: Please [edit] and add further details if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar this issue on a custom built desktop with Intel 10900K. I'm using a Corsair MP510 4T SSD as a boot/root device, firmware ECFM13.2. I'm booting UEFI.

The setup was working well for quite some time up until maybe 2 or 3 months ago. BIOS upgrade was done but the issue persisted.

This looks like a kernel bug/compatibility issue, I might try to downgrade to an old kernel.

This is hard to test, I might get a lockup once or maybe twice a week or so, despite using this machine all day every day.

Any more insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using this script to save the contents of the BERT from the dmesg output: https://gist.github.com/netom/748434e04970d10ebf2b0c983a45e47f

Comment: It could be a hardware issue, we've had similar behaving server (freezed once a week, or 2), it is reported via BMC as CATERR processor error, which could be caused by bad processor or motherboard.